# Excel : I want a sheet to only accept unique entries

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'm making an excel sheet for a group of people to work from. They will be adding entries identified by a unique alphanumeric string. I would like the entry of a repeated string to result in an error message, or ideally in the new entry overwriting the old.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look into `worksheet_change` event. But if each entry is unique, why would you want to overwrite the "old" one?

Comment: Use Data validation with a dynamic array pointing at the cells above to through an error if it found

Answer (score 2):

Using data validation.

Highlight all the cells from the second row to the bottom of the page.  Click data validation on the data tab.  Choose Custom and put in the following formula:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH($A2,$A$1:$A1,0))
```

Changing `A` to the column you want.

[image]

Now when I try to type a duplicate I get an error and cannot proceed till I fix it:

[image]